# Python3 crawl info after login

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib

I am trying to crawl my person information from a [website](http://www.jd.com) that requires login.

My work is below:

```
#coding:utf-8
import os, time
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# =================== urls ===================
login_url = 'https://passport.jd.com/uc/login'
info_url = 'http://i.jd.com/user/info'

# =================== post_data gathering ===================
login = urllib.request.urlopen(login_url )

loginSoup = BeautifulSoup(login,'html.parser')

uuid = loginSoup.find_all('form')[0].find_all('input')[0]['value']
clrName = loginSoup.find_all('form')[0].find_all('input')[6]['name']
clrValue = loginSoup.find_all('form')[0].find_all('input')[6]['value']

# jd login page captcha
checkPicUrl = loginSoup.find_all('div', id = 'o-authcode')[0].find_all('img')[0]['src2']
print(checkPicUrl)
# print(get_html('http:'+checkPicUrl))
image = urllib.request.urlopen('http:'+ checkPicUrl + '&yys=' + str(int(time.time() *1000)))

if image.getcode() == 200:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('http:'+ checkPicUrl , "checkPic.jpg")
else:
    print('unable to get image!')

os.startfile('E:\Projects\Python\jd_scrapy\checkPic.jpg')
checkCode = input('enter captcha: ') 

# # =================== cookie ===================
# # Storing cookies in cj variable
# cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
# # Defining a handler for later http operations with cookies(cj_).
# opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

# urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# =================== login ===================
login_info = {
    'chkRememberMe': 'on',
    'loginname':'<USERSNAME>',
    'nloginpwd':'<PASSWORD>',
    'loginpwd':'<PASSWORD>',
    'machineNet':'',
    'machineCpu':'',
    'machineDisk':'', 
    str(clrName):str(clrValue),
    'uuid':uuid,
    'authcode': checkCode
}

post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_info).encode(encoding = 'UTF-8')

session = requests.session()

# header
headers = { 
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
}

#login
passport = session.post(login_url, data = post_data, headers = headers)

print(passport) # <Response [200]>


# ============== page after login ==============

info_page =  urllib.request.urlopen(info_url)
info = info_page.read()
print(info)
```

The program runs fine with whatever captcha I enter, it returns  . I expected to see the raw html page after login but it shows nothing.

I don't think this program really login me into the account. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: It shows nothing or it throws an Attribute error? and if it throws an error, you should include the stacktrace.

Comment: @Craicerjack It was showing Attribute error but I edited it and now it shows nothing.